# What is the best way to convert from `Vec<T>` to `Vec<U>`?

Tags: rust

In my case I am converting from `Vec<u32>` to `Vec<usize>`.

Currently doing:

```
let usize_vec:Vec<usize> = u32_vec.into_iter().map(|x|x as usize).collect();
```

Answer (score 0):

That's the best way for your particular example, with `u32` to `usize`. If you want to use unsafe features to transmute the contents of the vector instead, you can use [`std::slice::align_to`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.align_to)/[`std::slice::align_to_mut`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.align_to_mut).

Comment: Please ensure that the question you are answering is not a duplicate before answering it.